# Postgres Dump Alter Queries

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm quite new to postgres and rusty with SQL having come from MySQL some time back.

What I want to achieve is to generate a dump file using an existing database structure, which I can then use to deploy changes to an environment which may or may not already include that database.

I assume this means the dump could consist of the following:

- Empty conditional `CREATE` queries for all tables (conditional as in 'if not exists'...)
- Conditional `ALTER` queries for all fields
- Conditional `ALTER` queries for all constraints and keys (primary and otherwise)

I am not interested in dumping the data right now.

Obviously this needs to be able to create the database structure where none exists, but mainly I'm interested in running the script where the database already exists, but the structure is not up to date. The idea being, that it would add relevant fields/keys/etc where none exist, bringing the database up to date.

I know deployment is a regular part of software engineering, so I'm assuming there is either:

- a simple way to do this, or
- a very good reason why this is not done.

Please provide one of the above as an answer. :)

Comment: You need to integrate this into your development cycle and simply do _every_ change to the database through scripts that are put under version control. Liquibase is a great tool manage schema migrations like that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you do this by automating the changes in the first place, then applying the same automation when you deploy to each instance. Tools like Liquibase can help you.

There are *lots* of good reasons it's not done as you describe:

- Some things, like column data type changes, are *very* hard to handle that way. You `ALTER` a column from `text` to `integer` `USING (NULLIF(trim(column)::integer, ''))` to strip whitespace and turn `''` into `NULL`. How would a dump know to do that?
- Sometimes a change appears to have no net effect, but is actually very important. `DROP TABLE mytable; CREATE TABLE mytable(...)` is very different to `ALTER TABLE mytable ...`, in that it clobbers the data, but when you're just looking at the DB state you don't see that.
- Sometimes when you're looking at states A and B it's hard to tell what transition(s) are actually required to go from A to B. There might be many ways to do it, or it might be impossible without going via some non-obvious intermediate state.

Trying to sync the data definitions is a *very* clumsy approach and it's very likely to break things.

Use schema versioning tools that can make a series of changes in a controlled way, based on a known starting schema version and a well defined set of transitions (migrations). Some frameworks provide such facilities built-in. For others you can use tools like Liquibase.

Comment: My typical example of a situation a diff cannot possibly detect: `alter table foo rename to bar;` The only thing a diff tool can (and will) do is to generate a `drop table foo` and a `create table bar`